# Apache Oltu Build Failure to run the demo

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, oltu

I would like to build oltu and run the client demo however the build fails due to missing dependency on the client. mvn jetty:run fails with the same error

I would appreciate any help

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Parent .............................. SUCCESS [1.158s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Commons ............................. SUCCESS [0.049s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Commons - Encoded Token ............. SUCCESS [1.175s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Commons - JSON ...................... SUCCESS [0.233s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 ........................... SUCCESS [0.089s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Common .................. SUCCESS [1.056s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Client .................. SUCCESS [1.108s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - HttpClient .............. SUCCESS [0.495s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Dynamic Registration Common SUCCESS [0.319s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Dynamic Registration Client SUCCESS [0.389s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Authorization Server .... SUCCESS [1.243s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Resource Server ......... SUCCESS [0.780s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Resource Server Filter .. SUCCESS [0.328s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Test Utils .............. SUCCESS [0.222s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Dynamic Registration Server SUCCESS [0.663s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - Integration Tests ....... SUCCESS [3.341s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OAuth 2.0 - JWT ..................... SUCCESS [0.574s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OpenId Connect ...................... SUCCESS [0.043s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OpenId Connect - Common ............. SUCCESS [0.118s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - OpenId Connect - Client ............. SUCCESS [0.428s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - JOSE ................................ SUCCESS [0.041s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - JOSE - JWS .......................... SUCCESS [0.968s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Demos - Parent ...................... SUCCESS [0.041s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Demos - Client ...................... FAILURE [0.029s]
[INFO] Apache Oltu - Reactor ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.577s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 28 16:39:21 PST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 57M/1021M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project org.apache.oltu.demos.client: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oltu.demos:org.apache.oltu.demos.client:war:1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oltu.openidconnect:org.apache.oltu.openidconnect.common:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT, org.apache.oltu.openidconnect:org.apache.oltu.openidconnect.client:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.oltu.openidconnect:org.apache.oltu.openidconnect.common:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://xxxxx/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One typical root cause of missing dependency is that the corresponding Maven repository was removed or inactive.

[Apache Oltu OAuth 2.0 Client and Provider](https://github.com/winstonhong/oltu) at GitHub repository is a fork of Apache Oltu with [Pull Request #10](https://github.com/apache/oltu/pull/10) for two new commits "Add provider demo and README".

You can follow the README instruction to build Oltu and run the OAuth 2.0 client demo and the OAuth 2.0 provider demo.